# DevExpress UI change

Tags: devexpress

I am attempting to modify TreeListColumns to behave like a GridColumn with regards to filtering.  I know that the TreeListColumns can filter, but would like to include the shortcut as performed by the GridColumn. This is running on a winclient.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have posted an example showing how this can be done at:
[How to make the TreeList control have a pop up column filter](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E2474.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be what I'm looking for but having difficulty setting a solution with the files to test it out.

I am receiving a number of compilation errors after adding references for: **Utils, XtraEditors, XtraLayout, XtraTreeList**. For example:

```
using DevExpress.Utils.Serializing;
```

gives an error that "The type or namespace name 'Serializing' does not exist in the namespace DevExpress.Utils"

and the one below

```
'TreeListFilter.CustomFilterForm' does not contain a definition for 'filterGroupPanel' and no extension method 'filterGroupPanel' accepting a first argument of type 'TreeListFilter.CustomFilterForm' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    251  21  TreeListControllFiltered
```

I am using DevExpress 10.1.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Download Example button on the top right corner of the site to check how the example works.  It will install the Example runner and convert the project to the DXperience Suite version you are using.  This will allow you to test the project.

Comment: I have to say, I'm pretty pissed off about having to install this example runner thing. I was happy just looking at visual studio solutions.